# Can't read arguments with getopt_long

Tags: c, getopt

I have the code below.
But when I run it with --debug=2, the debug variable gets value 100. I 'd expect 2...
Where is my mistake?
Here the code:

```
  int debug=0;
  int opt;
  struct option longopts[] = {
    { "debug",    required_argument, &debug, 'd' }
  };
  while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "d", longopts, NULL))!= -1)
  {
    switch (opt)
    {
      case 'd':
        switch (debug)
        {
          case 1:
            logPrio = LOG_INFO;
            printf("1");
            break;
          case 2:
            printf("2");
            logPrio = LOG_CRIT;
            break;
        }    
    }
  }
 printf ("--%d--", debug);
```

Comment: Note: if you want to have default behavior, create a header file and initialize your opt argument according to defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `&debug` in `longopts` doesn't store the integer value of the option to the specified address, `getopt_long` expects you to extract integer values yourself.

According to [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), the `int *flag` member of `struct option` does something completely different:

> `flag` "specifies how results are returned for a long option. [If
>   non-NULL], `getopt_long()`  returns 0, and flag points to a variable
>   which is set to `val` if the option is found, but left unchanged if
>   the option is not found.

You specify `&debug` for `flag` and `'d'` for `val`, so `debug` gets set to `'d'` (the number 100) when `--debug` is specified. Since you're already storing the result of `getopt_long` into the `opt` variable, you don't need to store `&debug` in `longopts` at all. Instead, use the `optarg` variable to get the argument to `--debug`:

```
  case 'd':
    debug = atoi(optarg);
    switch (debug) {
      ...
```

Comment: Also from memory you want `"d:"` not `"d"` as the parameter to getopt_long